# React useEffect vatibles are not defined outside the funtion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scope problem, I'm trying to declare a const varible inside useEffect hook from React but the varible is not beeing recognized outside the funtion.

```
import React, {  useEffect } from "react";

function Commentsbox(props) {

  useEffect(() => {
    //Connect to socket server.
  const socket = socketIOClient(baseUrl);
  }, []);

async function postComment(content, user) {
      fetch(`${baseUrl}/comment/post`, {  
//Do something.  
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
         socket.emit("msgToServer", newComment);
});     
    }
  }
```

As you can see what I'm trying to do is to make the client side emit new event called **"msgToServer"** as soon as response is coming from the server, but it keep throw that error **"socket' is not defined"**.

I tried to fix this by declare **socket** variable right above useEffect and giving it a value of undefined or null and then give it the value that I want inside useEffect() but still it does not define.

```
function Commentsbox(props) {
let socket;
useEffect(() => {
    //Connect to socket server.
    socket = socketIOClient(baseUrl);
  }, []);
}
```

I don't wanna give it value without using **useEffect()** hook because then it gives it the value a couple like 10 times which causes  10 connections to the socket.

Does anyone got any clue how to make it get the value?

Comment: The suggestion by @grzi is correct one. 
const variables are scoped to the function block, and they are not available outside the function provided to useEffect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use useState

```
function Commentsbox(props) {
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(initialValue);
useEffect(() => {
    //Connect to socket server.
    setSocket(socketIOClient(baseUrl));
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remember to include useEffect in your react import

```
import React, {  useEffect } from "react";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Make sure your code is up to date.
Check

> props.items